# Conflicting <li> styles

Tags: css

Here is the problem.
I had a nicely styled navigation. Then I added this side collapsible/expandable tree submenu, and the top navigation bar got distorted.
I know there is some conflict in styling li element for the top navigation and side menu.
I just can't figure out what exactly it is and how to fix it.
Maybe you will spot it.
Here is the URL:
http://eximi.dreamhosters.com/Hawaii/pkdiet/pkd.php 
You can see that the last item on the menu - "Contact us" jumps to the second line, which is not supposed to happen.

This is my CSS relevant to the issue:

/*Main navigation*/

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 132px; 
}

#menu li{
    display:inline;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    font-family: Tunga, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menu_item  a:link {
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    font-family: Tunga, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menu_item  a:visited {
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    font-family: Tunga, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.menu_item a:hover {
    color:#1e1d1d;
}

/* CSS Tree menu styles */
ol.tree
{
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    width: 130px;
}
    li 
    { 
        position: relative; 
        margin-left: -15px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    li.file
    {
        margin-left: -1px !important;
    }
        li.file a
        {
            color: #fff;
            padding-left: 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
    li input
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        top: 0;
    }
        li input + ol
        {
            background: url(images/toggle-small-expand.png) 40px 0 no-repeat;
            margin: -0.938em 0 0 -44px;
            xdisplay: block;
            height: 1em;
        }
        li input + ol > li { height: 0; overflow: hidden; margin-left: -14px !important; padding-left: 1px; }
    li label
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 17px;
    }

    li input:checked + ol
    {
        background: url(images/toggle-small.png) 40px 5px no-repeat;
        margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px; 
        padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
        height: auto;
    }
        li input:checked + ol > li { height: auto; margin: 0 0 0.125em;}
        li input:checked + ol > li:last-child { margin: 0 0 0.063em;}
```

Comment: On which browser are you testing it? It doesn't seem like it jumps to the second line for me on latest Chrome version.

Comment: Firefox and IE display it this way.
And by the way, the tree menu is not displayed in them correctly either.
The rest - Opera, Google Chrome, Safari - are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to set

```
#toggle
{
    margin-top: 54px;
    float:right;
    /*remove clear:both and margin-right:70px*/
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 132px; 
    width: 920px; /*in accordance with #wrapper*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph!
Just defining the #menu width fixed it.
But after that I did remove clear:both and margin-right:70px from #toggle and I don't see any difference.
Why did they need to be removed?
The tree menu still is not displaying properly in IE, but that's another issue.

Comment: @vlevsha You're welcome. :) I removed them when I was testing the site because it seemed to position the menu closer to where it shows in Chrome, FF, etc. but it wasn't necessary to fix the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong doctype, forcing the page into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), so it will never work as expected, particularly on IE.

Comment: changing it from quirks mode doesn't seem to help at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: HTML 4.01 is fine, but it's best to keep the Doctype declaration on the very first line, without any comments in front. Also check your site in the W3 validator (http://validator.w3.org/) and fix the errors, since HTML errors can cause unexpected CSS behavior. That may not be the cause of the problems now, but it'll help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First: specificity. Ids override classes, classes override elements.
If multiple styles apply, the most specific one is applied. This is done per line, so you only need to override the things you want to change.

If you do not want margins on menu items, you should add

```
#menu li {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

That cancels out `margin-left: -15px;` in the `li` element styling later.

Also I would not use a class `.menu_item` but instead target those items with `#menu li`. Every `.menu_item` is in `#menu` and every `li` in `#menu` is a menu item, so there's no need to introduce more classes.

**Update**

I think I've found the problem. These two lines need to be removed from `.menu_item  a:link {`:

```
float: left;
padding-right: 30px;
```

Floating elements inside inline elements doesn't seem to work too well.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought was a problem, and I did add margin-left: 0; to #menu li, but it didn't help.
As for the .menu_item vs. #menu li, I absolutely agree with you and am going to fix it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, what fixed the problem was adding width: 920px; to #menu as Joseph suggested here.